# How do i post the php form to another page

Tags: php, forms

```html
<head>
  <title>Admin Page</title>
  <?php require_once( 'raw_connect.php');
$sql="SELECT * FROM clients" ;
$result=m ysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
?>
</head>

<body>
  <form action='project.php' method=post>
    Client Name:
    <Select name="existing">
      <option value=1>Select a Client</option>
      <?php while($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)) echo "<option value=".$row[ 'ClientNo']. ">" . $row[ 'ClientName'] . "</option>"; ?>
    </Select>
    <br>Project Name:
    <input type=text name=projectname>
    <input type=submit value='Create Project'>
  </form>
</body>
```

so i have this form which displays a select box for the clients and a text box for the project. my problem is that whenever i try to process it, i get the error "Fatal error: Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1"
the page itself displays perfectly, its only when i hit submit that the error occurs on the next page.

after doing an inspect element i get this:

```
 "<form action="project.php" method="post">
        Client Name: <select name="existing">
               <option value="1">Select a Client</option>
               <option value="5">fred</option><option           value="7">louise</option><option value="8">ben</option>                </select>

      <br>
      Project Name: <input type="text" name="projectname">
      <input type="submit" value="Create Project">
    </form>"
```

project.php is:
     `

```
require_once('raw_connect.php');

$person= $_POST["existing"];
$projectname= $_POST('projectname');

$sql="SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ClientNo='$person'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo($projectname);

?>`
```

Comment: space between `m and ysqli_query ` at `m ysqli_query` and `m ysqli_fetch_array` create problem!!

Comment: this is project.php      <?php

require_once('raw_connect.php');

$person= $_POST["existing"];
$projectname= $_POST('projectname');

$sql="SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ClientNo='$person'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo($projectname);

?>

Comment: when you submit from on same page, no need for action in form.

Comment: the spaces arent there  in my code not sure how or why they got added

Comment: please [edit] you post and paste the code there.

Comment: `$_POST('projectname');` should be `$_POST['projectname'];`

Comment: that seems to have fixed it! thanks so much. pretty new to coding and switching bewtween the different syntaxes is really hard to keep track of

Comment: many typo's here, as i quickly look at it. I dont know what you program in but most editors have an auto fill function to already give you the item you are looking for. If it's done via notepad, try something called notepad++ It helps you debugging.

Comment: i use 'komodo edit' is that a bad choice, should i change to notepad++?

Comment: no, as i look at the documentation, you have acces to "Auto-complete & Calltips" turn that on. it will help you with writing your code.